# DB2 Locking scenario

Tags: db2, locking, db2-luw

Oracle does not locks the rows that are being read, Can anyone please let me know if DB2(LUW) grants lock for read or not? Would other transactions not be able to update row that is being read by another ongoing transaction?
Also is there a concept like undo segments in DB2 for providing read consistency?

Answer (score 0):

This table from the Knowledge Center describes the different lock modes:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0005270.html#c0005270__lockmod

This table has a comparison of isolation levels:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0004121.html?view=kc#c0004121__cil

In general, you should read the sections on "Concurrency" and "Lock Management" from which the above are taken

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Db2-LUW and undo segments.

Db2-LUW (versions 9.7 or higher) with CUR_COMMIT enabled (ON) uses the active-transaction-logs to read the currently-committed value of a row that a different transaction has updated-but-not-yet committed.

Db2-LUW present versions, does not employ undo tablespaces or use terminology such as undo segments.

Comment: consider the below scenario

emp_salary=4000

transacton 1
update employee set emp_salary=5000 where emp_id=123
(no commit or rollback issued)

transaction 2(isolation level is Cusror stability)
select emp_salary from employee where emp_id=123

what would be the output of second statement(4000 or 5000)?